# Hidden files showing in finder, but not in terminal

Tags: terminal, finder, filesystem

I'm setting up a new Mac running Monterrey 12.4.

I've used the standard method of the following terminal command:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles true; killall Finder
```

This doesn't allow me to see hidden files in terminal, only in Finder.

How can I always show hidden files when I use `ls` in the terminal?

Comment: The fine man page for ls(1) describes the '-a' and '-A' options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*How can I always show hidden files when I use `ls` in the terminal?*

You could add something like `alias ls='ls -a'` to one of your startup scripts.  Be careful though, changing the 'meaning' of `ls` might confuse more than it helps, so `alias lsa='ls -a'` might be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

To see the hidden files in the finder you can also use `cmd + shift + .` (period)

and to check it on the terminal `ls -a` -a stands for all the files.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make this behavior permanent and always show hidden files by default, you can create an alias for the `ls` command that includes the `-a` option. Add the following line to your shell configuration file (e.g., `~/.bash_profile` for Bash):

```
alias ls='ls -a'
```

After adding this line, restart your Terminal or run source `~/.bash_profile` to apply the changes. Now, every time you type `ls`, it will automatically include the `-a` option, showing hidden files.

Comment: Your answer is already covered by an existing answer to this question. Check [the help centre](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information on how to write good answers.

Comment: Also many if not most mac users will not be using bash now as the default is zsh and the bash version is 15 years old